# How to display image in Xamarin Form ContentPage IconImageSource

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Could anyone advice how to add the image in `ContentPage IconImageSource`?
Trying to display "icon.png" in Title bar.
The image from the ToolbarItem, "toolbar_icon.png", is able to display.
Both icons are place together in Android Resources drawable folder.
Haven't tried for iOS platform yet.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
             x:Class="HelloWorld.Views.AboutPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             IconImageSource="icon.png">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="toolbar_icon.png"></ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
</ContentPage>
```

App.xml file is default and doesn't update it.

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld.Views"
       Title="HelloWorldApp"
       x:Class="HelloWorldApp.AppShell">
    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png" Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/toolbaritem

Comment: @BasH I've checked and tried that. Able to display the image in ToolbarItem but not in ContentPage IconImageSource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Shell.TitleView` as the workaround .

```
    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Image Source="icon_feed.png"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </Shell.TitleView>
```

Refer to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58969359/8187800 .

Answer (score 0):

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Notes.Views.ConnectionPage"
             Title="Connection">

    <!-- Add an item to the toolbar -->
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="/Images/Satellite.ico"  />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
</ContentPage>
```